# Parse Time only (Minutes:Seconds.Ms) for SQL Server compliant C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, timespan

I have a string that has minutes.seconds.milliseconds. I need to convert this into a SQL Server compliant value of type `TIME`.

This is what I've tried so far but I'm still getting format exceptions

```
var a = "1.39.26";
        var ab = a.Split('.');
        var minutes = ab[0];
        var seconds = ab[1];
        var ms = ab[2];
        string time =  minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + ms;
        var one = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "mm:ss.FF",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var two = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "mm:ss.FF",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                 );
```

Also tried

```
string time = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + ms;
var one = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "dd-MM-yyyy mm:ss.FF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var two = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd-MM-yyyy mm:ss.FF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We *can't* know that what your `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()` returns since it depends on your `CurrentCulture` settings but you can *directly* parse this string to `TimeSpan` as;

```
var a = "1.39.26";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(a, "m\\.ss\\.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Later than you can add this value to your [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) if you want.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(ts);
```

But since [`TIME` mapped with `TimeSpan`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in CLR side, I doubt that you want this.

Further reading;

- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)